# I am looking for a way to test APIs on Laravel project with an API testing tool

Tags: php, laravel, api

I made an API with Laravel.
it needs to Auth.method is PUT.
How can I test it?

The respoce of API is 302

BODY
pretty
Sorry, the Chrome API does not allow to get a response body for redirect.

I reckon that my API test tool is not logged-in my laravel app so redirect happened.

P.S

Even after I commented out the Auth::user() this error still happens.

[image]

Comment: You need to be logged in to test the API. In such a case, you can call the login API. It should return an auth token. Store it in the header and call other APIs. It should be working then.

Comment: You can use the Guzzle HTTP library.

Answer (score 0):

The hack is you can comment out the middleware in api.php

Note: removing/commenting the middleware is definitely not a good solution but like you said you have commented out the Auth:user() so sharing the hack.

Correct way is shared by @Ramanath, Where you can login using login API(you can use the UI also and get the auth token from network too).  and put the token in the Authorization/header section like the screenshot below[image]